# dplyr equivalent of sql row_number() over (partition by group order by value)

Tags: r, dplyr, window-functions

**Initial situation**

I have a data set of the following form:

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- tribble(
  ~name, ~iq,
  "ben",  100,
  "alex",  98,
  "mia",  110,
  "paco", 124,
  "mia",  112,
  "mia",  120,
  "paco", 112,
  "ben",   90,
  "alex", 107
)
```

I'd like to create a new column which ranks, grouped by `name`, the values `iq` in descending order. In SQL one could write

```
select
  name,
  iq,
  row_number() over (partition by name order by iq desc) as rank
from
  dat;
```

which would produce the following expected output (already ordered for simplicity):

```r
#>   name     iq  rank
#>   <chr> <dbl> <int>
#> 1 alex    107     1
#> 2 alex     98     2
#> 3 ben     100     1
#> 4 ben      90     2
#> 5 mia     120     1
#> 6 mia     112     2
#> 7 mia     110     3
#> 8 paco    124     1
#> 9 paco    112     2
```

**Questions**

With my data, one can achieve the desired result with:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(rank = with_order(order_by = iq,
                           fun      = row_number, 
                           x        = desc(iq)
                           )
         ) %>% 
  arrange(name, rank)

#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   name [4]
#>   name     iq  rank
#>   <chr> <dbl> <int>
#> 1 alex    107     1
#> 2 alex     98     2
#> 3 ben     100     1
#> 4 ben      90     2
#> 5 mia     120     1
#> 6 mia     112     2
#> 7 mia     110     3
#> 8 paco    124     1
#> 9 paco    112     2
```

However, I don't understand *why* the code works. When reading the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/with_order) of `dplyr::with_order()`, it says the arguments are

- `order_by` = the vector to order by
- `fun`      = window function
- `x, ...`   = arguments to `f`

Given the description in the documentation and the working code, I have two questions I cannot answer:

1. What is the purpose of the argument `x`? Why not just specify the vector to order by and the window function (like in sql)? What is meant by `f`?
2. Why don't I have to write `order_by = desc(iq)`? To get the result I expect I have to write `x = desc(iq)` and set `order_by = iq`. This seems to contradict the documentation, which states that `order_by` = the vector to order by.

Comment: You could use just row_number() `dat %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(rank = row_number(-iq)) %>% arrange(name, rank)`

Comment: your solution is much simpler :)

Comment: As an alternative: `dat %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(rank = 1:n()) %>% %>% ungroup() %>% arrange(name, rank)`